# Custom form wordpress custom page

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, field, handler

Can you please tell me how to add single form with multiple fields around the page.

Is there possibility to use contact form 7 because I would like to get data to database/csv too. CF7 basic html coding window is not good enought to do full page there.

I also have read, Wordpress own admin-post.php might be work too in custom page form somehow.

Here is sample code what I mean:

```
 <?php/** * Template Name: Contact fields */ ?>
```

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <div id="form-start">
             <form action="" method="post">

                <div class="item">
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p><label for="field_1">Answer<span></span> <br><input type="text" name="field_1" value=""></label></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p><label for="field_2">Answer<span></span> <br><input type="text" name="field_2" value=""></label></p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p><label for="field_3">Answer<span></span> <br><input type="text" name="field_3" value=""></label></p>
                </div>

                <div class="last-item">
                    <p>INFORMATION</p>
                    <p><label for="field_4">Name<span></span> <br><input type="text" name="field_4" value=""></label></p>
                    <p><label for="field_5">email<span></span> <br><input type="text" name="field_5" value=""></label></p>
                    <p><label for="field_6">adress<span></span> <br><input type="text" name="field_6" value=""></label></p>
                    <p><input type="submit"></p>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>


        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

      </article><!-- #post -->

  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div><!-- #content --></div><!-- #primary --> <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: You can use CF7 with the `do_shortcode()` command. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I use cf7 shortcode, i have to build page in cf7 editor but the thing is how to build it in the custom page? or is it possible to use cf7 in there?

Answer (score 1):

The editor of CF7 is only used for the html of the contact form itself, not for the entire page.

so in the editor of CF7 you create your form. If you have trouble creating it please read the documentation first: http://contactform7.com/docs/

To show your form you can do 2 things:

1. Paste your shortcode in the wordpress editor.
2. [Create a custom template in wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) or edit an existing template from your current theme. And simply do: `<?php do_shortcode(['your-shortcode-here']) ?>`  at your desired location.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it seems to be the only option, if I want to use cf7. Another option is to make own php form and add it to the theme.